# Antdesign tabs role control

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to make a tab with Role based controlled tabpane, on the other hand, I can't see both component on the tabs.

[code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-microservice-vm6y2)

I added example. Can anyone solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Antd will scan the direct childrens of `Tabs` to construct the navigation. The better way to achieve this is to use conditionnal JSX :

```
{isAdmin && (
  <TabPane tab="Tab 3" key="3">
    Content of Tab Pane 3
  </TabPane>
)}
```

In the case that you want to inject datas to your table, you can pass props with another component, but cant hidse the navigation link because Antd weill detect it and add it to the nav:

```
<Role isAdmin tab="Tab 3" key="3">
  Content of Tab Pane 3
</Role>
// ...
function Role({ isAdmin, children, ...rest }) {
  // Work with isAdmin;
  return <TabPane {...rest}>{children}</TabPane>;
}
```

Comment: thank you but I want some think to usable globally. kind a Role management middleware higher order component. Is there any way to do that? Also I know conditional JSX. I think it looks mess in this case.